# R ggplot2 Add text to label geom_text

Tags: r, ggplot2

Based on the function below, how can I add `Formula =` `label = get_formula(model)` and `R^2(superscript) =`   `label = r_squared`?

Because when I do:

```
....
label = c("Formula = ", get_formula(model))
```

I get an error:

`Error in check_aesthetics(): ! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (42): label`

Code:

```
library(tidyverse)

df = data.frame(x = c(1:100))
df$y = 2 + 3 * df$x + rnorm(100, sd = 40)
p = ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
            geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE, color="black", formula = y ~ x) +
            geom_point()

get_formula = function(model) {
  
  broom::tidy(model)[, 1:2] %>%
    mutate(sign = ifelse(sign(estimate) == 1, ' + ', ' - ')) %>% #coeff signs
    mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ abs(round(., 2))) %>% #for improving formatting
    mutate(a = ifelse(term == '(Intercept)', paste0('y ~ ', estimate), paste0(sign, estimate, ' * ', term))) %>%
    summarise(formula = paste(a, collapse = '')) %>%
    as.character
  
}

lm(y ~ x, data = df) = model
get_formula(model)

scales::percent(summary(model)$r.squared, accuracy = 0.01) = r_squared

# Add the text to the plot:
p + 
  geom_text(x = 20, y = 300,
            label = get_formula(model),
            color = 'red') +
  geom_text(x = 20, y = 285,
            label = r_squared,
            color = 'blue')
```

Comment: Your code works fine when I replace `=` with `->`, i.e. `lm(y ~ x, data = df) -> model` and `scales::percent(summary(model)$r.squared, accuracy = 0.01) -> r_squared`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `paste` instead of `c` to concatenate into a string for the label. For getting the superscript you'll need a bit of unicode (as far as I am aware!):

```r
p + 
  geom_text(x = 20, y = 300,
            label = paste0("Formula = ", get_formula(model)),
            color = 'red') +
  geom_text(x = 20, y = 285,
            label = paste0("R\U00B2 = ", r_squared),
            color = 'blue')
```

[image]